# How can I make a SQL database, and use it in VB2010 (having more than 1 computer accessing the database)

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

The background to my problem is based on distributed computing. I want to have a database with some numbers in them and then a number of computers go through each row calculating another number (a little bit of an over simplification).

The problems I'm having are routed in my poor understanding of SQL servers (I think). I've got Microsoft SQL server 2012 (and 2008) installed on this machine and I've somehow managed to make a server for this task but then the problems arise.

I can't add a table to the server (I'm trying to do this in VS2010). When I expand the server and right click on tables and select add new table i get the following error:

"The server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 are supported."

That stops me making a table and from there I can't move on. I've downloaded and installed the VS2010 SP1 (and re-installed it again when it didn't fix the problem) as I found this suggested for similar issues.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I've read around but nothing seems to work, people suggest using "SQL Management Studio" but I don't seem to have this installed!

Also, I haven't gotten to this step yet, but if this gets fixed any advice/links on how to access the database from a different machine (over the same local network) would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,

Fraser

Comment: You can download SSMS from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R Harvey gave you the pointer to SSMS - that's the ideal tool to use.

As for other computers accessing your local database - the name of your computer (where MSSQL is installed) is the name of the server in your connection string.